# Make last three words of excerpt a link

Tags: permalinks

I'd like to have the last three words in an excerpt to be the link to the permalink instead of having a read more button. How would I do that?

Answer (score 3):

There are [different filters for the more-link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More), depending on whether you want it at the end of `the_content` or `the_excerpt`. Ultimately both work the same though. Selecting the last three words is a matter of PHP-skills. Like this:

```
add_filter ('the_content_more_link','wpse339250_three_words',10,2);
function wpse339250_three_words ($more_link, $more_link_text) {
  $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
  // split the excerpt in array of words
  $words = explode(' ', $excerpt);
  // starting at the third position from the end take three words
  $three_words = array_slice ($words, -3, 3, true);
  // replace the standard text in the link with the custom one
  return str_replace ($more_link_text, $three_words, $more_link);
  }
```

You may want to make a slightly more complex function to account for edge cases, such as the excerpt not being set or containing less than three words.

A different approach would be to kill the standard more-link altogether and use the [`get_the_excerpt`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_excerpt/) filter to wrap the last three words in the permalink. You'd need the same PHP-trick to find the last three words.